# Django - How to add custom error message in Form?

Tags: python, django, forms

How can I add a custom error message in a Django form?

For example, I want to add a new error message in a view if two e-mails aren't the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First you must define a function that begins with clean_[your field name] --- for example: def clean_email. Then write your validation in your function and assign an error name and use it in error_messages of your field.

```
class ValidationForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label = 'Email', error_messages = {'invalid': 'Your Email Confirmation Not Equal With Your Email'})
    email_confirmation = forms.EmailField(label = 'Email Confirmation')

    def clean_email(self):
       if email != email_confirmation:
          raise ValidationError(self.fields['email'].error_messages['invalid'])
       return email
```

Comment: Note you'll need to use the cleaned dictionary, in this case self.cleaned_data['email'], to get the user values (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)

Comment: I think you meant to say that you should define a 'method' not 'function'. Thanks, though.